# Сумма n слагаемых

Tags: c, вывод

Есть уже код программки,но вместо значений выводятся просто нули

```
int main() {
    int n,x,k=1;
    float S=0;
    printf("Введите n:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Введите x:\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        k *= i; 
        S += (-1^i)/((k+(i+1))*x);
        printf("S=%.3f ",S);
    }
    printf("\nSumma=%.3f",S);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знаете, что вы написали тут?

```
-1^i
```

Я вас огорчу - побитовое исключающее или `-1` и `i`, но никак не возведение в степень...

А тут

```
(-1^i)/((k+(i+1))*x)
```

Вы используете целочисленные переменные, так что вычисления тоже целочисленные... без дробных частей... :(

Если ищем, как вы написали,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то, на основании того, что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вынося `x` из-под знака суммы, получаем следующий код (`x` и `n` я прошил в коде, ввод пишите сами):

```
int main()
{
    double
        sum = -0.5,
        term = -0.5,  // Первый
        fact = 1.0;

    int n = 10; // Например
    double x = 1.0;

    for(int k = 2; k <=n; ++k)
    {
        term = -term*(1.0+(k-2)/(1+fact))/k;
        fact *= k;
        sum += term;
    }
    sum /= x;

    printf("Sum = %lf\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: то есть для корректного стоит использовать pow(-1,i) ?

Comment: Напишите-ка формулу ряда, мне восстанавливать ее из кода не хочется, да и гарантий, что вы ее верно запрограммировали, нет... Ну, а я тогда напишу, как.

Comment: ряд =  -1/((1+1)*х)+1/((2+2)*х)-1/((6+3)*х)+1/((24+4)*х)-... , в коде действительно ошибка, должно быть(по моему мнению): (pow(-1,i))/((k+(i))*x)

Comment: См. обновленный ответ